# How to add a transition to a slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my code for a page I am playing around with.

The main focal point is a div in the middle of the screen called screen. I have added a next and previous a tag to shift to the next slide. Everything is working well however I would like to make the change to another slide smoother by adding some sort of transition. For now, I will be happy with a fade-in fade-out transition.

I have tried so many different things and now am a little stuck. I dont know what I am doing wrong or what I am missing.

If anyone can help that would be great. Thank you.

Here is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Craig Frew | Profile Site</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="screen mySlides">
                <div class="screen-image-1 pan1"></div>
                <div class="screen-content">
                    <div class="screen-user">
                        <div class="container">
                            <span class="name">Welcome...</span>
                            <p>I have been working on updating my skills,<br>on this site I will showcase some of the projects I have been working on.<br>The goal is to have some leverage for when I am able to re-enter the work force.</p>
                            <div class="btn-contain">
                                <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
                                    <a class='btn-outline' href=''>
                                        <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                                        <span class='line-1'></span>
                                        <span class='line-2'></span>
                                        <span class='line-3'></span>
                                        <span class='line-4'></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="screen mySlides">
                <div class="screen-image-2 pan2"></div>
                <div class="screen-content">
                    <div class="screen-user">
                        <div class="container">
                            <span class="name">Technical Projects...</span>
                            <p>I love thinking logically so I have always been drawn to coding. <br>I know Python, HTML, CSS and I am currently learning JavaScraipt. <br> Here you will find the outcomes of this coding journey. </p>
                            <div class="btn-contain">
                                <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
                                    <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                                        <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                                        <span class='line-1'></span>
                                        <span class='line-2'></span>
                                        <span class='line-3'></span>
                                        <span class='line-4'></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="screen mySlides">
                <div class="screen-image-3 pan3"></div>
                <div class="screen-content">
                    <div class="screen-user">
                        <div class="container">
                            <span class="name">Creative Projects</span>
                            <p>I have been lucky enough to have music in my life from a young age. <br>Over the years I have collected a few snapshots to mark my musical career.</p>
                            <div class="btn-contain">
                                <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
                                    <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                                        <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                                        <span class='line-1'></span>
                                        <span class='line-2'></span>
                                        <span class='line-3'></span>
                                        <span class='line-4'></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="screen mySlides">
                <div class="screen-image-4 pan4"></div>
                <div class="screen-content">
                    <div class="screen-user">
                        <div class="container">
                            <span class="name">Contact</span>
                            <p>If you want to get in contact, you know what to do - click the button below!</p>
                            <div class="btn-contain">
                                <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
                                    <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                                        <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                                        <span class='line-1'></span>
                                        <span class='line-2'></span>
                                        <span class='line-3'></span>
                                        <span class='line-4'></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div class="dot-container" style="text-align:center">
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
                    <div class="test">
                        <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/home--v2.png" />
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
                    <div class="test">
                        <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/decentralized-network.png" alt="decentralized-network" />
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
                    <div class="test">
                        <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency-systems-regular/48/music.png" alt="music" />
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
                    <div class="test">
                        <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/contact-card.png" alt="contact-card" />
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="blob"></div>
            <div id="blur"></div>
            <script>
                // Get the DOM element with the id "blob"
                const blob = document.getElementById("blob");
                // Attach an event listener for pointer movement on the window
                window.onpointermove = event => {
                    // Extract clientX and clientY properties from the event
                    const {
                        clientX,
                        clientY
                    } = event;
                    // Animate the "blob" element to the new coordinates using CSS
                    blob.animate({
                        left: `${clientX}px`,
                        top: `${clientY}px`
                    }, {
                        duration: 3000,
                        fill: "forwards"
                    });
                }
                // Initialize the slide index variable to 1
                let slideIndex = 1;
                // Call the function showSlides with the initial slide index
                showSlides(slideIndex);
                // Function to navigate to the next or previous slide
                function plusSlides(n) {
                    // Call the function showSlides with the updated slide index
                    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                }
                // Function to navigate to a specific slide
                function currentSlide(n) {
                    // Call the function showSlides with the specified slide index
                    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                }
                // Function to display the slides based on the given index
                function showSlides(n) {
                    let i;
                    // Get all elements with the class "mySlides" and "dot"
                    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                    // If the index is greater than the number of slides, set it to 1
                    if (n > slides.length) {
                        slideIndex = 1;
                    }
                    // If the index is less than 1, set it to the last slide
                    if (n < 1) {
                        slideIndex = slides.length;
                    }
                    // Hide all slides
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                    // Remove the "active" class from all dots
                    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                    }
                    // Display the current slide and mark its corresponding dot as "active"
                    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried adding the transition property to the screen div but it did not work.

I have tried adding some code I found on the internet to the javascript but it never did anything. I am pretty new to this so to be honest I dont really know what I am doing!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question by providing the relevant code snippet here. It will help others to understand more clearly about your question and it will make it easy to answer to your question.

Comment: "*I have tried so many different things*" - Please add your attempts to the question as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a fade-in/fade-out effect on your slider, then you could use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Creating the fade effect can be done by animating the `opacity` attribute.
One way of solving this is just toggling a class, e.g. `active` on the element, which changes the opacity from `0` to `1`. The `transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;` property will take care of the "smoothing"

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}


div.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
<button type="button">Toggle</button>
```

---

```css
:root {
  --background-rgb: 15 15 15;
  --blue-rgb: 33 150 243;
  --primary-rgb: var(--blue-rgb);
  --blob-color-1: rgb(var(--blue-rgb));
  --blob-color-2: dodgerblue;
}

 :root {
  --clr-neon: hsl(60, 87%, 53%);
  --clr-bg: hsl(248, 80%, 43%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
  margin: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 55%);
  ;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  padding: 4rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.screen {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid white;
  /* border: 3px solid rgb(var(--primary-rgb) / 80%);
                      */
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  aspect-ratio: 10 / 16;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(var(--primary-rgb) / 15%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes pan1 {
  0% {
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: 20% 20%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 45%;
    background-position: 20% 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes pan2 {
  0% {
    background-size: 110%;
    background-position: 20% 20%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 30% 40%;
  }
}

@keyframes pan3 {
  0% {
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position: 20% 30%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 120%;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes pan4 {
  0% {
    background-size: 170%;
    background-position: 10% 70%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position: 0% 90%;
  }
}

.screen>.screen-image-1,
.screen-image-2,
.screen-image-3,
.screen-image-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(160deg);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.screen>.screen-image-1 {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ddya1vvc4/image/upload/v1691897305/clement-m-igX2deuD9lc-unsplash_jjxug8.jpg");
}

.screen>.screen-image-2 {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ddya1vvc4/image/upload/v1701148434/florian-olivo-4hbJ-eymZ1o-unsplash_cit764.jpg");
}

.screen>.screen-image-3 {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ddya1vvc4/image/upload/v1701148851/marius-masalar-rPOmLGwai2w-unsplash_xx3t0x.jpg");
  transition: all .75s ease;
}

.screen>.screen-image-4 {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ddya1vvc4/image/upload/v1701202751/annie-spratt-goholCAVTRs-unsplash_wqn7ed.jpg");
}

.pan1 {
  animation: pan1 15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.pan2 {
  animation: pan2 15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.pan3 {
  animation: pan3 15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.pan4 {
  animation: pan4 15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.screen>.screen-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 3;
  gap: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 95%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
}

.screen>.screen-content>.screen-user>.container>.name {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  color: antiquewhite;
  flex-grow: 3;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  word-spacing: 10px;
  text-shadow: rgb(63, 63, 61) 1px 0 10px;
}

.screen .screen-content .screen-user p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: antiquewhite;
  flex-grow: 3;
  text-shadow: rgb(63, 63, 61) 1px 0 10px;
  /* letter-spacing:5px;
                      word-spacing: 10px;
                      */
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .screen {
    scale: 0.6;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
  }
}


/* -- Blob effect -- */

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}


/* -- Blob effect -- */

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  50% {
    scale: 1 1.5;
  }
  to {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

#blob {
  background-color: white;
  height: 34vmax;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--blob-color-1), var(--blob-color-2));
  animation: rotate 20s infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#blur {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12vmax);
}

.dot-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 35px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  justify-content: center;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-inline: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 15;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.test {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-contain {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /* margin: 5% auto;
                      min-height: 100px;
                      */
}

.btn-outline-contain {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-outline {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgb(251 250 250 / 50%);
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: rgb(63, 63, 61) 1px 0 10px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  background-color: slategray;
}

.btn-outline:hover .btn-outline-inner {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline:hover .line-1 {
  animation: outline1 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline:hover .line-2 {
  animation: outline2 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline:hover .line-3 {
  animation: outline3 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline:hover .line-4 {
  animation: outline4 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.line-1 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333131;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.line-2 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #333131;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.line-3 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333131;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.line-4 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #333131;
  right: 0;
  top: 57px;
}

@keyframes outline1 {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  54% {
    height: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
  }
  55% {
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes outline2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes outline3 {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
  54% {
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
  }
  55% {
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes outline4 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  55% {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    right: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Craig Frew | Profile Site</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .mySlides {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .mySlides.active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="screen mySlides">
    <div class="screen-image-1 pan1"></div>
    <div class="screen-content">
      <div class="screen-user">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="name">Welcome...</span>
          <p>I have been working on updating my skills,<br>on this site I will showcase some of the projects I have been working on.<br>The goal is to have some leverage for when I am able to re-enter the work force.</p>
          <div class="btn-contain">
            <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
              <a class='btn-outline' href=''>
                <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                <span class='line-1'></span>
                <span class='line-2'></span>
                <span class='line-3'></span>
                <span class='line-4'></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="screen mySlides">
    <div class="screen-image-2 pan2"></div>
    <div class="screen-content">
      <div class="screen-user">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="name">Technical Projects...</span>
          <p>I love thinking logically so I have always been drawn to coding. <br>I know Python, HTML, CSS and I am currently learning JavaScraipt. <br> Here you will find the outcomes of this coding journey. </p>
          <div class="btn-contain">
            <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
              <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                <span class='line-1'></span>
                <span class='line-2'></span>
                <span class='line-3'></span>
                <span class='line-4'></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="screen mySlides">
    <div class="screen-image-3 pan3"></div>
    <div class="screen-content">
      <div class="screen-user">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="name">Creative Projects</span>
          <p>I have been lucky enough to have music in my life from a young age. <br>Over the years I have collected a few snapshots to mark my musical career.</p>
          <div class="btn-contain">
            <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
              <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                <span class='line-1'></span>
                <span class='line-2'></span>
                <span class='line-3'></span>
                <span class='line-4'></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="screen mySlides">
    <div class="screen-image-4 pan4"></div>
    <div class="screen-content">
      <div class="screen-user">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="name">Contact</span>
          <p>If you want to get in contact, you know what to do - click the button below!</p>
          <div class="btn-contain">
            <div class='btn-outline-contain'>
              <a class='btn-outline' href='#'>
                <span class="btn-outline-inner">Coming Soon</span>
                <span class='line-1'></span>
                <span class='line-2'></span>
                <span class='line-3'></span>
                <span class='line-4'></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dot-container" style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
                        <div class="test">
                            <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/home--v2.png" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
                        <div class="test">
                            <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/decentralized-network.png" alt="decentralized-network" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
                        <div class="test">
                            <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency-systems-regular/48/music.png" alt="music" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
                        <div class="test">
                            <img width="24" height="24" src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/contact-card.png" alt="contact-card" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="blob"></div>
  <div id="blur"></div>
  <script>
    // Get the DOM element with the id "blob"
    const blob = document.getElementById("blob");
    // Attach an event listener for pointer movement on the window
    window.onpointermove = event => {
      // Extract clientX and clientY properties from the event
      const {
        clientX,
        clientY
      } = event;
      // Animate the "blob" element to the new coordinates using CSS
      blob.animate({
        left: `${clientX}px`,
        top: `${clientY}px`
      }, {
        duration: 3000,
        fill: "forwards"
      });
    }
    // Initialize the slide index variable to 1
    let slideIndex = 1;
    // Call the function showSlides with the initial slide index
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    // Function to navigate to the next or previous slide
    function plusSlides(n) {
      // Call the function showSlides with the updated slide index
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    // Function to navigate to a specific slide
    function currentSlide(n) {
      // Call the function showSlides with the specified slide index
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    // Function to display the slides based on the given index
    function showSlides(n) {
      let i;
      // Get all elements with the class "mySlides" and "dot"
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      // If the index is greater than the number of slides, set it to 1
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      // If the index is less than 1, set it to the last slide
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
      }
      // Hide all slides
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
        slides[i].className = slides[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      // Remove the "active" class from all dots
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      // Display the current slide and mark its corresponding dot as "active"
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(function() {
        slides[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      }, 100);

      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```